# Solr JSON Request is not returning all data at once

Tags: json, parsing, solr

I'm using this pattern:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=hello&wt=json&json.wrf=?&indent=true&hl=true&hl.fl=title
```

It returns like:

```
?({
    "response":{"numFound":100,"start":0,"docs":[
        {
            "id":"1234",
            "title":"Something Hello"
            ..
            ..
        },
        ... bla bla, to the end
    ]
})
```

It is obviously showing `100 records found` in header but the items `{ bla bla... }` **really are `just 10` inside**. It is really the 100 item in the Index. IT MUST SHOW REALLY EXACTLY 100.

Is it showing just first 10 item?
What did i miss in the pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

100 is the total number of records that Solr found, but by default it only returns 10 at a time.

Try adding `&rows=100` to the URL to fetch all 100 results at once.

**Edit:** In a real app, you probably want to fetch results in pages, so that you don't run out of memory trying to fetch a zillion results at once. In that case, you combine the `start` and `rows` options.

For example to fetch 20 results at a time:

- First request would use `&start=0&rows=20`
- Second request would use `&start=20&rows=20`
- ... and so on, until you have fetched all the results.

This is similar to using the `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` keywords in SQL, if you are familiar with those.

Comment: Oooops, so what about other result counts that i can't know in advanced? How about next search will include 200? Can't it be done automatically with one generic setting?

Comment: @4lvin I've edited my answer to provide a bit more info which should help you.

Comment: So you mean, to show all for every search should be `rows=999999` like that?

Comment: Yes, but be careful that you don't run out of memory!